# Mobile Dev - How do you Replace .NET MessagingCenter with CommunityToolkit.MVVM?

Tags: mobile, maui, maui-community-toolkit, xamarin-community-toolkit

I wrote a mobile app and converted it from Xamarin to MAUI. I am getting a message stating that MessagingCenter is deprecated and to use CommunityTollkit.MVVM. I installed it but having issues converting the code.

This is the original code for MessagingCenter.

public Command MgmtCommand
{
get
{
return new Command((Vacation vacation) =>
{
//Unsubscribe from events - precautionary step to ensure that there are no existing subscriptions for the specified events
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe(this, "AddVacation");
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe(this, "UpdateVacation");

```
        //Navigate to the VacationAddView, passing a vacation if available
        Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new VacationMgmtView(vacation));

        //Subscribe to a MessagingCenter event for refreshing data when a new vacation is added
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Vacation>(this, "AddVacation", async (data) =>
        {
            //Refresh the vacation list data asynchronously
            await RefreshVacationListData();
            //Unsubscribe from the MessagingCenter event after refreshing data
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Vacation>(this, "AddVacation");
        });

        //Subscribe to a MessagingCenter event for refreshing data when a new vacation is updated
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Vacation>(this, "UpdateVacation", async (data) =>
        {
            // Refresh the vacation list data asynchronously
            await RefreshVacationListData();
            // Unsubscribe from the MessagingCenter event after refreshing data
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Vacation>(this, "UpdateVacation");
        });
    });
}
```

}

How do you change it to CommunityToolkit.MVVM so it works as it did with MessagingCenter. I am getting a number of errors.

```
    private async Task NavigateAndHandleAddUpdateAsync()
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<OpenWindowMessage>(this, HandleOpenWindowMessage);
    }

    private async Task HandleOpenWindowMessage(object recipient, OpenWindowMessage message)
    {
        switch (message.Value)
        {
            case true:
                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new VacationMgmtView(vacation));
                break;
            default:
                //await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Secondary window was closed", "OK");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what specifically are "a number of errors"?  And please fix the formatting of your code so its readable

Comment: If you see errors, why don't you show us said errors?